# What underlying semantic notions explain the meaning of 'against' for the preposition 'in'?

Tags: semantics, preposition

> [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in#Preposition_11) :]
>   1. (governs the ablative) in, at, on (space)  [quotations ▼]
>   2.  (governs the dative) within (time)
>   3.  (governs the accusative) into, to  [quotations ▼]
>   4.  (governs the accusative) about
>   5.  (governs the accusative) according to
>   6.  (governs the accusative) against

<sub>Though prepositions are Functional Morphemes, the semantics of prepositions have been scrutinised, studied, and successfully explained (in English and French, at least).</sub> This question focuses on 6 above:
what underlying semantic notions connect 'against' to 'in'?

To wit,  'against' (with its notion of conflict and opposition) superficially appears to contradict 'in' (with its notions of coherence and inclusion). So what  (in the semantic field of 'in')  would conciliate, mediate, and unite this superficial contradiction? Or what have I neglected (in the semantic field of 'in') that causes me to judge 6 as a contradiction?

Comment: If I’m running _towards_ you, brandishing a sword in my hand, would you think I’m being friendly? :-)

Comment: What Chirlu says. Cf. also English *leaning against the wall / fighting against the city*.

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks. Were you referencing the English ['without'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=without& allowed_in_frame=0) ? Otherwise, how does 'in' connect to 'against' in `leaning against the wall / fighting against the city`?

Comment: @LePressentiment: I was talking about *against*. It was just another example of how a neutral physical position can somehow become connected with a battle attitude.

Comment: @chirlu On a second reading, I do not understand your analogy, sorry. Why did you italicise *towards*; how does it connect with the Latin *in-*?

Comment: @LePressentiment: See the answer (*"In" plus the accusative, however, …*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you've neglected (an easy thing to neglect) is the *case* that "in" governs with each meaning. "In" plus the *ablative* connotes coherence and inclusion, and it's roughly equivalent to English "in." "In" plus the *accusative*, however, means something far closer to English "toward," which, if you think militarily (as the Romans often did), is fairly easy to convert into "against." So when Cicero was orating *in Catilinam*, he was rushing toward Catiline in the process of making an attack on him.

Comment: "Cicero's Preemptive Strike on Catiline".